# setText() method not displaying correct text in a custom view [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view

I have a custom view class consisting of 2 textviews, and a separate custom adapter class.
In the custom view class, I have a method to set the text of 2 textviews with implementation :

```
public class CompoundView extends LinearLayout {

private TextView versionNameView;
private TextView versionNumberView;
private Context mContext;

public CompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext=context;
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.ColorOptionsView, 0, 0);
    String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.ColorOptionsView_titleText);

    int valueColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ColorOptionsView_valueColor,getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
    a.recycle();

    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_color_options, this, true);
    versionNameView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
    versionNumberView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_item_content);

}

public CompoundView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);


}

public void setTexts(String text1,String text2) {
    versionNameView.setText(text1);
    versionNumberView.setText(text2);
} 
}
```

and in my custom adapter, inside the overridden getView() method section, I implemented :

```
...
CompoundView customView = new CompoundView(yContext);
customView.setTexts("Test1","Test2");
...
```

And when I run the app, the text in the UI is showing its original value (the one that is originally declared in XML instead of the one that is programmatically declared).
However, if I try to do  `versionNameView.getText()` and `versionNumberView.getText()` inside the custom view, the logcat is showing the correctly updated value.
So what are the steps I should do in order to get the updated text to be properly shown in the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to properly work.
Instead of creating an object of the view, I should use the operation `findViewById()` to refer to existing created custom view in the XML file.